# AWK -Print the next to last field of each line of input file

Tags: awk, field

I have an input file file the content of which constantly is updated 
with various number of fields, what I am trying to is to  print out to a new file 
the next to last field of each line of input file:
awk  '{print $(NF-1)}' outputfile

error:
and
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Need help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

On lines with no fields (blank lines, or all whitespace) `NF` is 0, so that evaluates to `$(-1)`. Also if there's only one field your code will print `$0` which may not be what you want.

```
awk 'NF>=2 {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score -1):

another awk line: (golfing a bit):

```
awk 'NF>1&&$0=$(NF-1)'
```

Comment: Does it work? `echo foo | awk 'NF && $0 = $(NF-1)'` outputs `foo`.